# LateInitializationError: Field 'data' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I am trying to create a new Food to Firestore. And I get this error:

LateInitializationError: Field '_currentFood@678306641' has not been initialized.

And here is my code:

**My Model**

```
 class Food {
  late String id;
  late String name;

  Food();

  Food.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    name = data['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }
}
```

**My Notifier**

```
class FoodNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  late Food _currentFood;
   
  Food get currentFood => _currentFood;

  set currentFood(Food food) {
    _currentFood = food;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**And Here is Page Create**

```
  class FoodForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isUpdating;

  FoodForm({required this.isUpdating});
  @override
  _FoodFormState createState() => _FoodFormState();
}

class _FoodFormState extends State<FoodForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  late Food _currentFood;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FoodNotifier foodNotifier =
        Provider.of<FoodNotifier>(context, listen: false);

    if (foodNotifier.currentFood != null) {
      _currentFood = foodNotifier.currentFood;
    } else {
      _currentFood = Food();
    }
  }

Widget _buildNameField() {
return TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
  initialValue: _currentFood.name,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onSaved: (String? value) {
    _currentFood.name = value!;
  },
);
```

}

**I tried changing like this in my Model**

```
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;

  Food({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Food.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) => Food(
        id: data['id'] as String,
        name: data['name'] as String,
      );

  Map<String, Object> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
      };
}
```

**and FoodNotifier**

```
Food? _currentFood;
Food? get currentFood => _currentFood;
```

Then I will get this error message The return type of getter 'currentFood' is 'Food?' which isn't a subtype of the type 'Food' of its setter 'currentFood'.

Comment: Change the data type in setter as well like `set currentFood(Food? food)` to allow null as a value.

Comment: Well I tried it, and no more errors